# Populate Min/Max based on Issues and lead time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to write an sql update query to populate the min/max fields based on the issues and the date issued.  I am looking at 120 days delivery as my delivery date.

| PN | QTY_ISSUED | ISSUED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2 | 20-01-01 |
| 12345 | 1 | 20-02-01 |
| 12345 | 2 | 20-03-01 |
| 12345 | 5 | 20-04-01 |
| 12345 | 1 | 20-04-20 |
| 12345 | 3 | 20-06-01 |

I would like to return and update to `11` and not return the `3` in June.

Comment: OK.  What have you attempted?

Comment: 120 days delivery from what epoch? Are your dates in `YY-MM-DD` or `DD-MM-YY` format? Please [edit] your question to explain the logic in more detail.

Comment: 120 days based on the issues over that period of time.  I am having trouble with pulling data based on 120 days in multiple rows.